# HTML Structure for jQuery append with Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've seen such a thing before and I forgot to bookmark it. It was a plugin for something, wish I knew what was it for to keep searching.

Anyway I need to learn how to create a HTML structure within jQuery using array.
I remember that guy who made a plugin that I've seen have used following:

```
var struct = [];

.join(), .pop(), .push()
```

I tried these but I can't figureout how to create such a thing and append it into body.
I always create a default structure like this.

```
$("body").append(//->
  '<div class="daBox-outer">' +
    '<div class="daBox-inner">' +
      '<div class="daBox-top" />' +
      '<div class="daBox-bottom" />' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="daBox-overlay" />' +
  '</div>'
//<-
);
```

Please if anyone know how to make such a structure using array, let me know with an example! Link redirect to any plugin that has structure made with jQuery arrays is also welcome, so I can learn out of it.

Comment: That code is not valid and the question is unclear, what is it?

Comment: FYI, this is javascript array, not jQuery array

Comment: how would your array look that you want to use with the plugin?

Comment: @gdoron looks valid to me

Comment: @A.Wolff : `var struct = [];

.join(), .pop(), .push()` is valid? in what language?

Comment: @gdoron that is a question... How to make similar structure to mine, using these...

Comment: @gdoron that's ok, i was talking about the append() snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
var structure = [];
var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
mydiv.className="myClass";
structure.push(mydiv);

//then all you need to do

$("body").append(structure);
```

What it does:
It creates new element div it adds the div to the array finally it appends it you can do the document.body.appendChild if you want to go through pure js.
You can view this jsfiddle - [Click!](http://jsfiddle.net/cST74/)

Comment: That's close to what it looked like in that plugin... But still, guy had empty array, creating each div, adding class to it, closing, pushing each to array and then joining.

Comment: Ok so you can do it more or less this way: you create div using var myDiv = document.createElement("div"); mydiv.className = "myclass"; var structure = []; structure.push(mydiv); and you will have it in array then you do what I answered above.